# WP Query ordering on a meta field for posts with a date in the future not ordering by datetime

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a WP Query:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 5, 
'category__in' => $postCategories,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'ordering_date',
        'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATETIME',
    ),
),
'order'     => 'ASC',
'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'ordering_date',
'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',

);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Based on the query I would expect:

1. Post 1: with ordering_date of 2022-04-07 00:00:00
2. Post 2: with ordering_date of 2022-04-11 00:00:00
3. Post 3: with ordering_date of 2022-05-02 00:00:00
4. Post 4: with ordering_date of 2022-05-24 00:00:00
5. Post 5: with ordering_date of 2022-07-11 00:00:00

But instead, the order is:

1. Post 3
2. Post 8
3. Post 9
4. Post 2
5. Post 4

What is wrong with my query that is its not ordering the posts based on the ordering_date meta field?

TIA

Comment: Try removing the `'meta_key' => 'ordering_date',` and `',
'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'` from your `$args` array. But this to me sounded like being caused by a plugin or custom code (in the active theme) which might be filtering the query (args), so you could try deactivating plugins and see if the same issue persists. Before that though, try inspecting the generated SQL command - `echo $query->request;` and add the output to your reply or the question body.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, `'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ it was indeed a plugin wreaking havoc.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad it helped, but I should make it clear that you shouldn't need to set the `meta_key` and `meta_type` args, because you already have the `meta_query` array which correctly sets the meta `key` and `type`, hence the `meta_key` will lead to an unneccessary table join. So keep just the `meta_query` and `'orderby'  => 'meta_value'`, and you'd get the expected outcome or sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are a little vague in this area, but it should be possible to define your ordering value more succinctly:

```
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'category__in' => $postCategories,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ordering_date',
            'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATETIME',
        ),
    ),
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_datetime',
    'meta_key' => 'ordering_date',
    );
```

Comment: this did work in conjunction with a plugin issue

Comment: So would you like to mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Actually @vancoder, with the original code in question (which uses `'orderby'  => 'meta_value'`), I got `ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATETIME) ASC` which I believe is the correct one. But when I used your code (which uses `'orderby'  => 'meta_value_datetime'`), I got `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC`. So I wondered where in the WordPress docs or source which stated/implied that `meta_value_datetime` (or `meta_value_<meta type>`) works?  And BTW, I tested on a default WordPress v5.9.3 install.